# getJSON update not updating

Tags: jquery, getjson

On this site: http://www.rent-turkey-property.com/

I have it set so that when you select a region from the dropdown (left box) it pulls in the towns for the town menu using jQuery.getJson

My code worked when it was in the head of each page but seems to have broken when moved into an external file (or maybe another change broke it, sure I checked it after transfer to external)

The trouble is everything seems to be working fine. Firebug is telling me I have the data, but it won't update select#town

Driving me insane.

UPDATE:

Update

I have now found that it is an error with the JSON (parsererror Invalid JSON) but it worked fine before and I haven't changed it.

The only thing I have changed, that I haven't been able to reverse for testing is upgrading to the latest version of jQuery, has JSON standard changed in latest version (1.4.2).

Here is my JSON:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['region'] == "Aegean") {
  echo <<<HERE_DOC
[ 
{optionValue: 'Altinkum', optionDisplay: 'Altinkum'},
{optionValue: 'Bodrum', optionDisplay: 'Bodrum'},
{optionValue: 'Cesme', optionDisplay: 'Cesme'},
{optionValue: 'Dalaman', optionDisplay: 'Dalaman'},
{optionValue: 'Dalyan', optionDisplay: 'Dalyan'},
{optionValue: 'Fethiye', optionDisplay: 'Fethiye'},
{optionValue: 'Icmeler', optionDisplay: 'Icmeler'},
{optionValue: 'Gocek', optionDisplay: 'Gocek'},
{optionValue: 'Kusadasi', optionDisplay: 'Kusadasi'},
{optionValue: 'Marmaris', optionDisplay: 'Marmaris'},
{optionValue: 'Oludeniz', optionDisplay: 'Oludeniz'}
]
HERE_DOC;
} else if ($_GET['region'] == "Mediterranean") {
  echo <<<HERE_DOC
[
{optionValue: 'Alanya', optionDisplay: 'Alanya'},
{optionValue: 'Antalya', optionDisplay: 'Antalya'},
{optionValue: 'Belek', optionDisplay: 'Belek'},
{optionValue: 'Kalkan', optionDisplay: 'Kalkan'},
{optionValue: 'Kas', optionDisplay: 'Kas'},
{optionValue: 'Kemer', optionDisplay: 'Kemer'},
{optionValue: 'Saklikent', optionDisplay: 'Saklikent'},
{optionValue: 'Side', optionDisplay: 'Side'}
]
HERE_DOC;
} else if ($_GET['region'] == "Istanbul") {
  echo <<<HERE_DOC
[{optionValue: 'Istanbul', optionDisplay: 'Istanbul'}]
HERE_DOC;
}?>
```

Comment: Using source control is very beneficial in situations like this.  It makes change tracking trivially easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your keys in quotes:

```
[ 
{'optionValue': 'Altinkum', 'optionDisplay': 'Altinkum'},
{'optionValue': 'Bodrum', 'optionDisplay': 'Bodrum'},
{'optionValue': 'Cesme', 'optionDisplay': 'Cesme'},
// ... other entries ...
]
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. Unfortunately it never worked either. Even a simple call to .getJSON and adding each item in the response to an element, Ajax has same error

Comment: Turns out you are right, I must have made a boob when adding quotes to keys on my attempt. Problem arose because of jQuery 1.4 changing to use the native JSON parser, as oppose to EVAL as in previous versions

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content type of your ajax responses to application/json instead of text/html.

Answer (score 0):

Use "json" instead of "application/json" in the `dataType` option in your call to $.ajax().

The problem is that jQuery isn't converting the HTTP response content to JSON, so your success function is iterating through a string.

Also, your iteration function is referring back to the original array, not the current item.  Either use `resp[index]`, `this`, or add an `element` argument to the function.

```
success: function(resp){
    var options = '';
    $.each(resp,function(index) {
        options += '<option value="' + this.optionValue + '">' + this.optionDisplay + '</option>';
    }
```